# Remove the same image watermark from every page of a pdf file

Tags: windows, pdf, adobe-acrobat, documents, watermark

I am in possession of a long PDF file. On each and every page of this file there is an annoying watermark/logo that I wish to remove. The printing shop unlawfully added their own logo on somebody else's work while scanning the document.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsE9e.png) is a screenshot of a random page of the document. I circled in red the watermark that I'm trying to remove. Thanks.

EDIT: this question is not a duplicate. The other answers are literally not working in my case. The watermark in my case is part of the page SCAN, it is not metadata in the pdf file. Please read the questions before closing them.

Comment: Is it ever on top of any text or anything important?

Comment: And is it always in that exact location?

Comment: Hi, the location changes around the page. It is never on top of text, just in blank spaces.

Comment: I would like to know how is ths question a duplicate when it is totally a different thing. My pdf does not have a SCRIPTED or EMBEDDED watermark. It cannot be removed with the methods proposed in the "duplicate" answers because my wtaermark is part of the SCAN of the page. Please take time to read questions before closing them.

Comment: I think this watermark is a "part" of the pdf now, meaning it was added before or during scan, Its as if the stamped it physically, So the pdf reader will see it as part of the original not as a watermark. I could be wrong, but I think your only hope is to put something on top of it like a white box in a photo editor or pdf editor.

Comment: Yes, this is not a duplicate. However, the difference means it will be very difficult to remove the watermark. The easiest method would be to speak to the print shop that "unlawfully" did this and have them correct their work. If it is truly unlawful, they should be willing to remove the mark without additional compensation.

Comment: I was looking for a software that could programmatically look for the "watermark" logo in each page and cover that with a white color, for example. Even if it takes many hours, I don't mind. @music2myear we already discussed that, they will not remove the watermark and nobody is in possession of the originals anymore. This is a 2012 document, so my only hope is to make it work on this pdf.

Comment: Manual method could be export to BMP, remove mark using photo/image editor, then create new PDF from edited BMP files.

Answer (score -2):

1. first uncompress the pdf file

`pdftk input.pdf output uncompressed.pdf uncompress`

2. identify the watermak line

open the uncompressed pdf file in text editor, i.e. vim, gedit, notepad++, etc.

search 'Watermark' and identify the watermark line, i.e.

```
EMC /Artifact <</Subtype/Watermark/Type/Pagination>> BDC /FXE2 gs q 0.476256 0 0 0
FXX4 Do Q
```

3. delete all the duplicated watermark lines, in this case, let's use '0.476256 0 0' as line indicator, then delete by

```
sed -i '/0.476256 0 0/d' ./uncompressed.pdf
```

4. compress the pdf file back

```
pdftk uncompressed.pdf output output.pdf compress
```